# Can I find out whether my DNS provider honor my TTL settting?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, ttl

Is there any way to determine if my DNS provider actually use the TTL setting I provide?

Comment: Do you mean "I have put a set of RRs into my DNS providers website, including TTLs, how can I confirm that the provider is exporting those TTLs to the world unchanged"?

Comment: @MadHatter Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Then `dig` is your friend, as Tutul has already said.  You should substitute your domain for `gmail.com`, and your nameservers in turn for `ns1.google.com`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$dig @ns1.google.com +nocmd gmail.com A +noall +answer

gmail.com.      300 IN  A   74.125.235.53
gmail.com.      300 IN  A   74.125.235.54
```

the second column here is the TTL value (300)

Answer (score 0):

The website http://www.mxtoolbox.com/ can tell you that information.